# Facebook comments moderation, appid or facebook page?

Tags: facebook-social-plugins

I'm looking to add Facebook comments to certain pages of our website.
I understand that I can do this by just generating the code for each page I want comments on by using the generator here... http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

But to enable moderation of comments I think I need to do either of these in the head section of my site:
`<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}">`
And also add some namespaces to the `<html>` tag.

The application ID method seems better than user ID for moderating a large number of comment pages.
At the moment I have a Facebook "Page" with 1,000 or so "Likes". I don't have a Facebook application.

So here's my questions:

Do I need to create a Facebook Application in addition to my Page?
Or can I use the Facebook Page ID instead of the App ID?
Does the name of the Application need to match that of my Facebook Page?
Is any link created between the Facebook Application and the Page?
Or is the application purely for internal purposes and not accessible by users?

I don't want this to be Javascript. Iframes seems like a better solution so the comments load asymmetrically. JS can block the page load.

Cheers, B

Answer (score 2):

Any time you make an application that will use facebook you need to make a facebook application on their developers website. Pages are different from applications. The only thing that I ever use a page Id for is likes, thought there are other uses for them

Your application does not need to match the page, but you may want to

A) Make it a tab of that page

[image]

B) Disable `Stream post URL security` on the developers page (better for you I think)

[image]

Comment: So would that application be available for people to browse and add to their facebook pages? Like Marketplace and Scrabble etc? Or is it purely for private moderation use?

Comment: Well, you do need to make a canvas page, but it will not be linked to anything. I currently have a few that I have, and no one goes on them. They are only important for testing while in sandbox mode (need to add testers, ect.) but after that there for moderation only.

Comment: I see. So do I then need to setup admins of the application if I want them to be able to moderate comments? Or does it just copy my page admins?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure on that one, we usually just link it to that page, and the company takes care of all that. I think the page is responsible for it though

Comment: Ok I've created an application. How do I link it to my page? Or can the two just exist separately and the application is just for moderators?

Comment: You may want to go with option B `Disable Stream post URL security ` See edits

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about this on: http://codeitdown.com/facebook-comments-moderate-button/
Short answers are:

- **Do I need to create a Facebook Application in addition to my Page? Or
  can I use the Facebook Page ID instead of the App ID?**
  You need an application in addition to your page to enable "advanced" moderation. The page ID cannot be used.
- **Does the name of the Application need to match that of my Facebook

  Page?**
  No
- **Is any link created between the Facebook Application and the Page? Or is the application purely for internal purposes and not accessible by users?** You can link your application and page or just don't tell anyone about your app and use it for moderation only.